# Local description of the universal family $\pi: \overline{\mathbf{U}}_{0,n} \longrightarrow \overline{\mathbf{M}}_{0,n}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, moduli-spaces, coarse-moduli-spaces, k-stability

I would like to get an understanding of the notion of geometric fibers of the universal family:
$$\pi: \overline{\mathbf{U}}_{0,n} \longrightarrow \overline{\mathbf{M}}_{0,n}.$$
In fact Knudsen show that family is of the form
$$ \mathbf{V}\times\mathbf{Q} \longrightarrow \mathbf{V} \times \mathbb{A}^1$$
where $\mathbf{V} \subset \overline{\mathbf{M}}_{0,n}$ and $\mathbf{Q}=\lbrace (x,y,z)\in \mathbb{A}^3: xy=z \rbrace.$

Moreover, in local coordinate we have $\mathbb{A} \simeq \mathbf{V}.$ Also for n=4, $\overline{\mathbf{U}}_{0,4}$ is the bowup at three point of $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ or $\overline{\mathbf{M}}_{0,4} \times_{\overline{\mathbf{M}}_{0,3}}\overline{\mathbf{M}}_{0,4}.$
So, how to show that the geometric fibers of the family are reduced?

Comment: Can you please explaiin some of the notations used?

Comment: I do not understand the question. By definition the fibers are stable curves, hence reduced.